# Pycharm gives a warning with an enum created using functional syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, pycharm, enumeration

I am writing an enumeration using function-call (functional) syntax, like this:

```
from enum import Enum

Color = Enum('Color', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'])
myColor = Color.RED
print(myColor)
```

The enumeration example is taken from the [Python 3.11.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/enum.html). The code runs fine, and the expected answer "Color.RED" is printed, but Pycharm gives a warning:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'RED' for class 'Enum': 3
```

According to the documentation, the previous example is equivalent to the following one, using class syntax:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

myColor = Color.RED
print(myColor)
```

Pycharm does not give any warning with this code. I am using Pycharm 2022.2.5 with Python 3.11.4.

So, my question is: is there any problem with the example using functional syntax, is it a bug of Pycharm, or the documentation should clarify that both approaches are actually not equivalent?

Comment: Since this is not a new syntax (at least not since Python 3.7) and that `mypy` does not complain, I'd file this as a bug in PyCharm.

Comment: The two enums are equivalent; typing enums is hard (or, at least, laborious).  Pycharm should be updated (it's probably low-priority as class-created enums are more common).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug with PyCharm that has been open for ages.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36205/False-unresolved-attribute-reference-for-enum-value